# Functional JavaScript, remove assignment

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How can I avoid the `self` variable here?

```
function urlBuilder(endpoint){
    var status = ["user_timeline", "home_timeline", "retweets_of_me", "show", "retweets", 
            "update", "update_with_media", "retweet", "unretweet", "retweeters", "lookup"
        ],
        friendships = ["incoming", "outgoing", "create", "destroy", "update", "show"]; 
    let endpoints = {
        status: status,
        friendships: friendships
    }

    var self = { };

    endpoints[endpoint].forEach(e => {
        self[e] = endpoint + "/" + e;
    });

    return self;

}
```

somewhat better, still an assignment statement.

```
return [{}].map(el => {
  endpoints[endpoint].forEach(e => {
    el[e] = endpoint + "/" + e;
  });
  return el;
})[0];
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: because it's midnight, mainly.  just exploring.

Comment: In my understanding, your first approach was better. You are adding an extra and unnecessary iteration because of `.map`. Also, `self` is a conventional name for context variable. This will reduce the readability instead.

Comment: @Rajesh I agree with the poor name, and agree that the second is less readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot really. To create an object with a dynamic number of properties (and without using `JSON.parse`) you always need to mutate it by assignment or something similar.

Your best bet might be

```
return endpoints[endpoint].reduce((self, e) => {
    self[e] = endpoint + "/" + e;
    return self;
}, {});
```

which is quite functional.

Comment: what about this? for a functional way to get an object with a dynamic number of properties. https://jsfiddle.net/ny4x17a0/

Comment: @MegaMan you're using assignment to `acc` just as any other solution. And `arr.shift()` is absolutely non-functional (and slow on top of that) as you are mutating your input (!); you really should simply use `reduce`.

Comment: i realized on the way home that it wasn't any better :/ and the first iterations i was getting a shift is not defined error on the second go around since shift returns the element that was shifted, not the rest of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` too.

It does mutate the `acc` but it's localized to the `reduce` call.

```
endpoints[endpoint].reduce((acc, e) =>
  Object.assign(acc, { [e]: `endpoint/${e}` }), {})
```